# Need my div dropdown menu to hide text when not hovered

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, transition

I'm trying to do a dropdown menu with a div. The transition on the div is fine and everything is working great. But I don't know how to get the text that's in the dropdown area do be hidden when I'm not hovering?

Html code. not much but it is droping down as it should. I don't want menu to be hidden only the text writen below it.

```
<div class="dropdown">Menu
    <br/>Games
    <br/>Food 
    </div>
```

CSS code. Transitions and all.

```
div.dropdown
{
    position:absolute;
    width:920px;
    height:20px;
    top:110px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-460px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:gray;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s ease;
    background:black;
    text-align:center;
    color:White;
}

div.dropdown:hover
{
    height: 45px;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.1s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

in the .dropdown class.

This will allow you to hide everything that displays outside of the elements bounds.

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvqxt/1)

Comment: I didn't know you could do it this way. Very cool. It doesn't seem super scalable, but it is cool.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html so that your dropdown items are in an ordered list `<ul>` inside the div

Add some css so that the list is normally hidden

```
div.dropdown ul{
   display:none;
}
div.dropdown ul:hover{
   display: block;
}
```

Also, remove the existing height limit on the dropdown div.

then some JavaScript/jQuery to make the list appear when you hover over the menu

```
$('div.dropdown, div.dropdown ul').on('hover', function(){
   $('div.dropdown ul').show();
}
$('div.dropdown, div.dropdown ul').on('mouseleave', function(){
   $('div.dropdown ul').hide();
}
```